# Вывести количество комментариев для статьи

Tags: php, sql

Как вывести количество комментариев для статьи?

Всего 14 статей, комментарии имеют только 2 статьи.
У одной 1 комментарий, а у другой 2 комментария.

Данный код мне выводит везде 2 комментария и в одной 3 комментария, почему так?

```
SELECT questions.question_name, COUNT(*) AS countComment 
FROM questions INNER JOIN users LEFT OUTER JOIN comments
ON comments.questions_id = questions.id 
AND comments.questions_id = questions.id 
AND questions.user_id = users.id 
GROUP BY questions.id
```

Если сделать так:

```
SELECT questions.question_name, COUNT(*) AS countComment 
FROM questions INNER JOIN comments WHERE comments.questions_id = questions.id
 AND comments.questions_id = questions.id GROUP BY questions.id
```

То правильно выводит комментарии, но не выводит статьи, которые без комментариев.

Comment: для юзеров условие склейки не хотите прописать ?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь одним LEFT JOIN,

Comment: `count()` считает НЕ NULL значения. когда он с `*` он всегда считает _строки_. А количество строк у вас всегда минимум 1 - сам вопрос, даже если комента нет. И `LEFT JOIN` пишите без `OUTER`. Возвращаясь к первой части - `count(comments.questions_id)` даст именно кол-во коментов, ибо у строк без коментов в этом поле будет NULL.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)

Comment: Теперь, если этот запрос добавить в тот, который я хочу, то там всё путается. Вот этот запрос выводит всё правильно http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1d9c0a1c9b844354f71b67ff166180ab38816db9                            И если к нему, добавить счётчик комментариев, то данные путаются, неправильно подставляются логины, города и улицы http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e0c70172feb003775c5aca5069b5ae7a6fc71c2f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
questions.id, 
questions.question_name, 
questions.answer, 
questions.variant1, 
questions.variant2, 
questions.variant3, 
questions.variant4, 
questions.user_id, 
questions.city_id, 
questions.street_id, 
questions.date, 
questions.img, 
users.login, 
city.city_name, 
street.street_name, 
COUNT(comments.questions_id) as countComment 

FROM questions 
INNER JOIN users ON questions.user_id = users.id 
INNER JOIN city ON questions.city_id = city.id
INNER JOIN street ON questions.street_id = street.id 
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.questions_id = questions.id 
GROUP BY questions.id ORDER BY `date` DESC
```